# How to replace a variable in wordpress plugin though function.php

Tags: php, wordpress

```
public static function getCatalogStrings()
    {
        return [
            'booking_appointment'    => __('Booking Appointment', 'wpamelia'),
            'buffer_time'            => __('Buffer Time', 'wpamelia'),
            'categories'             => __('Categories', 'wpamelia'),
            'category_colon'         => __('Category:', 'wpamelia'),
            'description'            => __('Description', 'wpamelia'),
            'description_colon'      => __('Description:', 'wpamelia'),
            'extras'                 => __('Extras', 'wpamelia'),
            'info'                   => __('Info', 'wpamelia'),
            'maximum_quantity_colon' => __('Maximum Quantity:', 'wpamelia'),
            'view_more'              => __('View More', 'wpamelia'),
        ];
    }
Above code is written in plugin. I want to write 'Book now' instead of 'View More' through function.php without editting plugin.
```

Above code is written in plugin. I want to write 'Book now' instead of 'View More' through function.php without editting plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Use [gettext](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext) filter.

Example:

```
function prefix_filter_gettext( $translated, $original, $domain ) {

    if ( $domain == 'wpamelia' ){
       // Use the text string exactly as it is in the translation file
       if ( $translated == 'View More' ) {
           $translated = 'Book now';
       }
    }

    return $translated;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'prefix_filter_gettext', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: This will change View More in every screen. You have to restrict it to specific scenario.

Comment: do expand on shazyriver:  use the $domain to check for 'wpamelia'

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [Loco Translate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/) plugin and override the desired string from the admin panel